# why does aws sagemaker data wrangler not allow me to deploy model in canvas

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-data-wrangler

I'm logged in with an administrator account. I'm using aws sagemaker data wrangler in canvas. When I try and deploy the model but I get the message 'you don't have permissions to deploy models. Please contact your administrator for support'

Any reason why I can't deploy? I used the quick build option. Could this be a factor? or is this a permission problem?

I was using quick build option. It says when you use quick build option you can't share quick build models. Does this also mean you can't deploy a quick build model? It doesn't say it.